# How do I call a JavaScript function as soon as an HTML element is created?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I created a loop inside jsp which takes 10 movies from a database. Each movie is assigned a unique id (the variable `elementId`) and the rating for that movie is also found(the variable `userRate`).

I have a function `fillRateButton` which gets `elementId` and `userRate` as parameters and gives that movie a specific style. I want it to run for each movie that get created as soon as it gets created. That's why I put a script tag before the end of the for loop.

```
<script> fillRateButton("<%=elementId %>",<%=userRate %>); </script>
```

The problem is that this doesn't work and I can't call my function using `onload()` because the variable `userRate` changes.

```
<% 
     String email = ((request.getSession()).getAttribute("emailSession")).toString();

     for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
           Movie movie = GetMovie.simply();
           String movieSrc ="images/movies/m" + movie.getMovieId() + ".jpg";
           int userRate = UserRates.getRates(email, movie.getMovieId());

            String elementId = "element"+i;
%>

    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-white w3-border w3-padding">
        <div class="w3-col s5">             
            <div style="width:100%;height:200px">
                <img src="<%= movieSrc %>" alt="<%=movie.getMovieName() %>" class="w3-border w3-round " style="width:100%;height:100%">
            </div>
    <!-- Rate the movie -->
    <div class= "w3-container w3-teal w3-padding-left" id="<%=elementId %>">
        <span class="fa fa-heart w3-hover-text-pink w3-xlarge rateButton" style="cursor:pointer;color:white;" onClick="addFill(this,2);addRating(2,<%=movie.getMovieId() %>)"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up  w3-hover-text-blue w3-xlarge rateButton" style="cursor:pointer;color:white;" onClick="addFill(this,1);addRating(1,<%= movie.getMovieId() %>)"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-down  w3-hover-text-black w3-xlarge rateButton" style="cursor:pointer;color:white;" onClick="addFill(this,0);addRating(0,<%= movie.getMovieId() %>)"></span>              
    </div>
                <script> fillRateButton("<%=elementId %>",<%=userRate %>); </script>

    <%} %> <!-- End of the for loop -->
```

my javascript function which is located just before closing body element

```
const fillRateButton = (element , rate)=>{
    let rateMenu = document.getElementById(element);
    let list = rateMenu.getElementsByClassName("rateButton");
    if (rate===2)
        list[0].style.color = "#ff1a40";
    else if (rate===1)
        list[1].style.color = "blue";
    else if (rate===0)
        list[2].style.color = "black";

};
```

I am not familiar with the jQuery library so if you answer in plain JavaScript I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t
And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: The confused me even more. but I tried putting my script tag inside <head> and it worked.